# how to set max value in quantity update in codeigniter cart

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php echo form_input('cart[' . $item['id'] . '][qty]', $item['qty'], max=> $item['price'] ' type="number"  min="1" value="1" )'; ?>
```

how to set max value it shows me syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to pass associative array,

```
<?php 
      echo form_input(
             array(
               'name'=> 'cart[' . $item['id'] . '][qty]', 
               'type'=>"number",
               'min'=>1,
               'max'=> $item['price'],
               'value'=> $item['qty'], 
              ) 
      ); 
?>
```

You still can correct your existing one like below

```
<?php 
    echo form_input(
              /*name*/
             'cart[' . $item['id'] . '][qty]',  

             /* value */
             $item['qty'],                       

             /* other attributes as string */
             'max="'.$item['price'].'" type="number" min="1"'           
     ); 
?>
```

**From :** https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

> `form_input([$data = ''[, $value = ''[, $extra = '']]])`
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> $data (array)   – Field attributes data
> $value (string) – Field value
> $extra (mixed)  – Extra attributes to be added to the tag 
>                   either as an array or a literal string
> ```

Comment: still it is accepting value more than $item['price'] when updating cart, how can i show up notification if input  exceeds max value?

Comment: @turaco on submission validate it server side, if submitted more, then show error